# Graphing time on y-axis on a bar chart with plotly

Tags: python, datetime, plot, bar-chart, plotly-python

Having a pd.Series `dff` like this:

```
0    1900-01-01 00:05:43
1    1900-01-01 00:05:58
2    1900-01-01 00:04:13
3    1900-01-01 00:03:58
4    1900-01-01 00:04:41
5    1900-01-01 00:04:53
6    1900-01-01 00:04:39
7    1900-01-01 00:04:38
8    1900-01-01 00:06:59
9    1900-01-01 00:06:26
10   1900-01-01 00:04:06
11   1900-01-01 00:04:19
12   1900-01-01 00:05:13
13   1900-01-01 00:03:39
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I would like to plot a bar chart very similar to the scatter plot I created
[Scatter plot picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag42x.png)
using this code:

```
fig_bar = px.scatter(dff, x=dff.index, y=dff.values)
fig_bar.update_yaxes({'type': 'date', 'tickformat': '%M:%S'})
```

but instead of the points I would like bars going from the bottom to the point for every value in `dff.index`. Unfortunately, simply changing `px.scatter` to `px.bar` makes it unreadable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that'll help us to solve your problem. Can you share the output of the code that converts the series data to bar plot? What's the issue you are facing with that code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.